# How to Set up base path for ckfinder in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have installed CKEditor and CKFinder in the directory like root->NEWS->ckeditor &

root->NEWS->ckfinder but I want use ckeditor & ckfinder on this file

root->NEWS->International->AddNews.aspx

So problem here is how to load filebrowser using exact base path.

ex.
In code behind AddNews.aspx.cs

```
CKFinder.FileBrowser ckf = new FileBrowser();         
ckf.BasePath = "ckfinder/"; /*default for root installation of ckeditor & ckfinder*/
ckf.SetupCKEditor(DetailsView1.FindControl("CKEditorControl1"));
```

What I am getting:

http://localhost:40407/NEWS/International/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images&CKEditor=ContentPlaceHolder1_DetailsView1_CKEditorControl1&CKEditorFuncNum=2&langCode=en

But It should be:

http://localhost:40407/NEWS/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images&CKEditor=ContentPlaceHolder1_DetailsView1_CKEditorControl1&CKEditorFuncNum=2&langCode=en

Please help me. What would be the exact BasePath for this?

Answer (score 0):

If `ckfinder/` is supposed to be a root directory, use either

```
ckf.BasePath = "/ckfinder/";
```

or

```
ckf.BasePath = Server.MapPath("~/ckfinder");
```

Your path, as you've shown it, is relative from the page in which you use it. `~` is interpreted by the ASP.NET runtime as the site's virtual root, which will be resolved by MapPath to the actual root directory's path.

Comment: I got the answer which is similar like above... ckf.BasePath="/NEWS/ckfinder/"